# Identify my rear aero brake

Tags: brakes, identify-this-bike, parts

I'm looking to buy a new aero brake, after the noodle holder on my old set has snapped (and apparently i need to replace the whole thing).

Problem is that i can't find the model anywhere.  I've looked at the [trp T925](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/fr/fr/freins-trp-t925-aero/rp-prod150548?gs=1&sku=sku549051&pgrid=108383258543&ptaid=pla-293946777986&utm_source=google&utm_term=&utm_campaign=&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mkwid%257c_dc%257cpcrid%257c467278531671%257cpkw%257c%257cpmt%257c%257cslid%257c%257cprd%257c549051FR%257c&pgrid=108383258543%29&ptaid=pla-293946777986&gclid=CjwKCAiAjeSABhAPEiwAqfxURaLYbEaTmCUSZMvAfwRDHizPQ9_cGnXKUJchGLaJz7NHC36fgb8gSxoC_IEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and [trp 925.1](https://trpcycling.com/product/t925-1-rear/), but I'm pretty sure that it's not the same.

As a starting point, it came from a felt b16 (2016/2017 i think) (responses from their european branch have been limited, i assume due to the current climate).

Here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [T822](https://trpcycling.com/product/t922t922-1/). But I don't think you necessarily need an exact replacement. Shimano, Campagnolo, and other companies have made bottom-bracket direct-mounted brakes as well, and any of them would probably be a drop-in replacement, although clearance could be tight. I think the [T850](https://trpcycling.com/product/t850851/) would also work.

Comment: And your brake cable is in urgent need of replacement, it is broken with loose frayed strands and since it does not have an end cap, there is a high risk of personal injury.

Comment: That's the one!  Thankyou very much for the help.

Comment: @Carel concur - to do the job properly, a new inner/outer and noodle should be used.

Comment: @Preston Check the crank arm for damage too - you’d be surprised how much damage steel-on-aluminum scraping can cause after a while.